# Nameservers vs URL Forwarding

Tags: html, web, dns, server

I have a domain name that I got from a domain name register. I think I understand that "url forwarding" means whenever someone types in the domain name I own, they are redirected to a different URL. It seems like there is something else called "nameservers" which may or may not do the same thing. Can anyone clarify these two terms?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so you registered a domain name. That means you "own it" temporarily for as many years as you registered it for. Now you have to do something with that domain. Possibilities:

1. Point your domain to a hosting service where your website files will be stored and used. This will be the new home of your domain name. This can be done by either modifying your domain's nameservers or A Records. To do this simply find out what the nameservers of your hosting provider are and change them in your freenom account. Ex  NS1.YOURHOSTINGCOMPANY.COM and NS2.YOURHOSTINGCOMPANY.COM.

After changing your nameservers you can modify your website via Dreamweaver, Aptana, Filezilla, etc. all directly via your hosting service or the Server you set up.

2. Forward your domain to an existing domain (url forwarding); basically another dot com. When a user types in your domain name it will forward to a different location. There are several ways of doing this. a) 301 Permanent Redirects; b) 302 Temporary Redirects; c) cloaking using frames (not recommended).

   - 301 and 302 redirects are used to forward the domain and so your visitors will see the domain name they are forwarded to, not the original one. Ex. If you forward sample1.com to sample2.com visitors will see sample2.com in their url bar.
   - Cloaking (or masking your URL). The end user does not know they are being redirected because they continue to see sample1.com in their url bar even though they are really visiting sample2.com. I recommend you do not use this method because Google frowns upon this and may penalize you as far as Search Engine Rankings are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

There's a little difference. Let me explain domain forwarding:

You've bought a new domain called evanadler.com, and you would like it to be forwarded to evanadler.co that's possible with domain forwarding.

Now let me explain a name server, with name servers you can assign an IP Address to your domain. For example if my server IP is 1.2.3.4 my DNS record would be evanadler.com -> 1.2.3.4. Name servers are mostly name servers from your hosting provider since it's the best way to manage your DNS there. But if you're more technically you might like to manage it your self.

Answer (score 0):

Typing in a URL in the browser and seeing a website open involves several steps on several layers. Let's say you type "`example.com`" into your browser, then the following happens:

1. The domain name `example.com` must be resolved to an *IP address* first. This is done through a *name server*. This is essentially what you buy when you buy a domain name; the right to configure the domain name to point to a name server of your choice which can resolve the name to an IP address of your choice.

   - The DNS system is checked for the name server responsible for `example.com`.
   - That name server is asked for the IP address ("`A` record") of `example.com`.

   The browser now has the IP address of the web server of `example.com`.
2. The browser now makes an HTTP request to the IP address discovered in step 1, asking it for the website "`example.com`". This is where any *HTTP response* may be obtained. One possible HTTP response could be a redirect to a different domain.

So, to make a domain redirect to another domain, you need to:

- buy the domain name
- set up its name server (`NS`) record to point to a name server of your choice
- set up said name server to point to a web server's IP address
- set up said web server to respond with an HTTP redirect to a different domain

Depending on where you got the domain, some or all of those steps may be rolled into a single one-click choice, but they're still all necessary behind the scenes.